# A problem about affine spaces

Tags: analytic-geometry

Let A be an affine space,dim(A)=4.

P,Q are planes from A.

If dir(P)!=dir(Q),then P and Q are disjoint.

Is this proposition true or false?

I know that two planes are parallel if they are disjoint only for an affine space B with dim(B)=2 or 3,but I don't know this assumption is true for 4-dimensional spaces.

Please,could you help me?

Comment: What is $dir(P)$?

Comment: dir(P) is the vectorial space that lies below the 2-dimensional affine subspace P.

Comment: And what would be $dim(P)$? Two or three? I it is two, then I'd try to adapt the case of two intersecting  lines $\{z=0,\,x+y=0\}$ and $\{z=0,\,x-y=0\}$ in 3D-case to your 4D.

Comment: dim(A) is four.

Comment: dim(P) is two.That is the value of dim(P).

Comment: Please,could anyone help me at this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $dir(P)=dir(Q)$, then $P$ and $Q$ can be either disjoint $P\cap Q=\emptyset$ or $P=Q$.

If $dir(P)\ne dir(Q)$, then we can find examples when $P\cap Q\ne \emptyset$ (take any planes $P$ and $Q$ such that $P=dir(P)$ and $Q=dir(Q)$) and when $P\cap Q=\emptyset$. Just take $$P=\{x_1=1,\,x_3=0\}$$ and $$Q=\{x_1=-1,\,x_2=0\}.$$

Comment: What is P={x1=1,x3=0}?

Comment: Please,could you tell me?